# How many times any word occurred in string. Each letter case (upper or lower) in word matters. Lines in output can be in any order.:

Tags: python

How many times any word occurred in string. Each letter case (upper or lower) in word matters. Lines in output can be in any order.:

**We tried list and we tried dicts also we tried Zen**

I have tried this:

```
sequence_of_sentences = ['We tried list and we tried dicts also we tried Zen']
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter()
for sentence in sequence_of_sentences:
    counts.update(word.strip('.,?!"\'') for word in sentence.split())
print(counts)
```

but how can I list them like it:

```
and 1
We 1
tried 3
dicts 1
list 1
we 2
also 1
Zen 1
```

Comment: have u tried anything??,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> for key,value in counts.items():
...     print(key,value)
...
dicts 1
also 1
list 1
Zen 1
and 1
We 1
we 2
tried 3
```

Answer (score 1):

collections.Counter is `dict subclass` for counting hashable object, where element are stored
as key and count as their value. so u can apply all functions of dict:

```
for key,value in counts.items():
    print(key,value)
```

you can also use collections.defaultdict, it is faster than counter.

```
>>> my_dict = collections.defaultdict(int)
>>> a
'We tried list and we tried dicts also we tried Zen' 
>>> for x in a.split():
...     my_dict[x] +=1
... 
>>> my_dict
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'list': 1, 'We': 1, 'Zen': 1, 'tried': 3, 'also': 1, 'dicts': 1, 'we': 2, 'and': 1})
```